# Perl indent doesn't use space

Tags: eclipse, perl, epic

I am using Eclipse Luna. I have installed the Perl EPIC plugin. I want to indent 4 spaces instead of <kbd>TAB</kbd>.

I have checked `Window` -> `Preferences` -> `General` -> `Editors` -> `Text Editors` -> `Insert spaces for tabs`, but still when there is need to auto indent a new line, Eclipse still indents with TAB instead of spaces.

How do I change it so EPIC will use spaces instead of tabs for indentation in Perl files?

Comment: Editor formatters usually have specific settings which override the General. For Java you find them under `Java->Code style->Formatter`. I imagine it's something similar for Perl

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but there is no formatter for perl and I have changed Java->Code style->formatter to Space only, but still no help to the perl indention

Comment: it is strange, when I click TAB, it does replaced by 4 spaces, but when I need to auto-indent, the script is indented by a TAB not 4 spaces

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but I ran into the same issue, found this post, and subsequently how to change the formatting settings for Perl EPIC in Eclipse.

- From the main IDE workspace, click the `Window` menu and then choose `Preferences`.
- Scroll down to `Perl EPIC` and expand it in the tree.
- Click the `Editor` entry.
- In the right panel under the `Appearance` tab, you can change your preferences for `Insert tabs/spaces on indent` and whether or not to use spaces instead of tabs.